# how to create nested templates on Backbone

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript

I'm new on Backbone and I'm trying to click on a Button on the toolbar (located on toolbar div), the button is called "New".
After click I want to open a new panel on a different div with id= "app-list".

But when pressing on the new button it always override the "app-list" div

Here is my code(I'm using Backbone and coffeescript):

```
class MyApp.Views.ToolbarAppView extends Backbone.View
  el: "#toolbar-app"

  events: "click #add_new": "newApp"

  newApp: (e) ->
    myapp = new MyApp.Models.App
    @model = myapp
    newPanel = new MyApp.Views.NewAppView({ el: @$el, model: @model, parent: @})
    newParent.render()

 class MyApp.Views.NewAppView extends Backbone.View
   template: JST["myapp", "new_app_view"]

   render: ->
     fieldsPanel = new MyApp.Views.EditAppView({ el: @$el, model: @model, parent: @})
     fieldsPanel.setElement('#app-list').render()



class MyApp.Views.EditAppView extends Backbone.View
  template: JST["myapp", "edit_app_view"]
  tagName: "tr"
  className: "edit_data"

  render: ->
    @$el.html(@template({ el: @$el, model: @model, parent: @})
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing how your HTML structure looks, it's not easy to deduce what might be the problem. However, there's something funny going on these two lines here:

```
fieldsPanel = new MyApp.Views.EditAppView({ el: @$el, model: @model, parent: @})
fieldsPanel.setElement('#app-list').render()
```

In the constructor you set the view's `el` to the `ToolbarAppView`'s `el`, and on the following line you change the element to another one.

Try replacing the two lines with the following:

```
fieldsPanel = new MyApp.Views.EditAppView({ el:'#app-list', model: @model, parent: @})
```

If that fails, consider editing your question with more info, especially regarding the relevant parts of your HTML templates.